# getting data from two different table using the same column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: `u_user` and `Clients`. The id column in u_user is the same as user_id in Clients, I wanna pull information from the two tables in one page.

I expect output like

u_user id username Password 2 user123 pass123 Clients id user_id name Class 1 2 James 200

I wanna use the season id which is = to id in u_user and equal to user_id from "client" to pull information from both tables

```
<?php 
   include('dbcon.php');
   include('session.php'); 
   $result=mysqli_query($con, "select * from u_user where id='$session_id'")or die('Error In Session');
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 ?>
```

Comment: please elaborate your question it is incomplete. you have to give table names & value and your complete code. specify the problem in a clear way.

Comment: you should just `SELECT * FROM u_user JOIN Clients ON u_user.id = Clients.user_id`